# Get list from dataframe with no header - pandas python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a lot of CSVs with no header on them. They are all only 1 column and they have a bunch of links.

I am trying to iterate over all the CSVs and put them into a single python list so I can perform a for loop over the list.

From what I have seen, it seems you can only use `to_list()` when use `names` for columns, but what about CSVs with no header name?

Code:

```
def pandadownload():
    listgather() #this function grabs all the CSVs in a directory and returns a list
    csvlist = listgather.csvval
    for csv in csvlist:
        pandadownload.df = pd.read_csv(csv,index_col=0, header=None)
        print(pandadownload.df)
    return pandadownload.df
```

Result (it looks like a list but when I try to use a for loop on it, it can't find anything):

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [https://downloads.khinsider.com/game-soundtracks/album/-t-w-y-a-o-gyakuten-meets-jazz-soul/01%2520-%2520Ace%2520Attorney%2520-%2520Court%2520Begins%2520Blue%2520Note%2520Scale.mp3, https://downloads.khinsider.com/game-soundtracks/album/-t-w-y-a-o-gyakuten-meets-jazz-soul/02%2520-%2520Phoenix%2520Wright%2520-%2520Objection.mp3, https://downloads.khinsider.com/game-soundtracks/album/-t-w-y-a-o-gyakuten-meets-jazz-soul/03%2520-%2520The%2520Steel%2520Samurai.mp3, https://downloads.khinsider.com/game-soundtracks/album/-t-w-y-a-o-gyakuten-meets-jazz-soul/04%2520-%2520Justice%2520For%2520All%2520-%2520Court%2520Begins%2520Blue%2520Note%2520Scale.mp3, https://downloads.khinsider.com/game-soundtracks/album/-t-w-y-a-o-gyakuten-meets-jazz-soul/05%2520-%2520Miles%2520Edgeworth%2520-%2520Great%2520Revival.mp3, https://downloads.khinsider.com/game-soundtracks/album/-t-w-y-a-o-gyakuten-meets-jazz-soul/06%2520-%2520Furio%2520Tigre%2520-%2520Swinging%2520the%2520Tiger.mp3, https://downloads.khinsider.com/game-soundtracks/album/-t-w-y-a-o-gyakuten-meets-jazz-soul/07%2520-%2520Trials%2520and%2520Tribulations%2520-%2520Court%2520Begins%2520Blue%2520Note%2520Scale.mp3, https://downloads.khinsider.com/game-soundtracks/album/-t-w-y-a-o-gyakuten-meets-jazz-soul/08%2520-%2520Godot%2520-%2520The%2520Fragrance%2520of%2520Dark%2520Coffee.mp3, https://downloads.khinsider.com/game-soundtracks/album/-t-w-y-a-o-gyakuten-meets-jazz-soul/09%2520-%2520Rise%2520From%2520the%2520Ashes%2520-%2520End.mp3, https://downloads.khinsider.com/game-soundtracks/album/-t-w-y-a-o-gyakuten-meets-jazz-soul/10%2520-%2520Trucy%2527s%2520Theme%2520-%2520Child%2520of%2520Magic.mp3]
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Try using index to get column and then make a list. I think its df.iloc[index]

Comment: Or maybe `df.index.tolist()` would work?

Comment: Actually, it looks like you should be using `index_col=False`. That should make your code able to accommodate multiple columns.

Comment: At the moment, your first column is being used as an index. If your csv only has a single column, this will produce an empty dataframe. I'm assuming that all data in the csv should be present in the output list and not assigned to external values (column name or row index) that would be dropped.

Comment: I tried using `index_col=False` before I made this post and that didn't work. It kept indexes within the dataframe. Also It still doesn't seem to give me a list. I don't think a dataframe is a list. I think I need to use `to_list()` but I am not sure how to do that when none of my CSVs have any headers

Comment: Having index values in the dataframe shouldn't matter as long as it's a default value and not originating from your csv. You should use `index_col=False` as well as `df.values.tolist()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For testing I used a dummy csv with following data:

[image]

I removed `index_col`:

> index_col (int, str, sequence of int / str, or False, default None)
> Column(s) to use as the row labels of the DataFrame, either given as
> string name or column index. If a sequence of int / str is given, a
> MultiIndex is used.
>
> Note: index_col=False can be used to force pandas to not use the first
> column as the index, e.g. when you have a malformed file with
> delimiters at the end of each line.

Applied `iloc` to get first coulmn:

```
import  pandas as pd

def pandadownload():
    # listgather() #this function grabs all the CSVs in a directory and returns a list
    # csvlist = listgather.csvval
    csvlist = ['urls.csv']
    for csv in csvlist:
        pandadownload.df = pd.read_csv(csv, header=None)
        print(pandadownload.df.iloc[:,0].values)
    # return pandadownload.df

pandadownload()
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: This worked for me. I realized that I had to make a list of lists as I have multiple CSVs and each CSV comes out as a list. so I did this: `pandadownload.fullcsvlist.append(pandadownload.df.iloc[:,0].values)` (I changed the variable name to `pandadownload.fullcsvlist` when testing) and this gave me what I was looking for. Thank you for your help!!